# Adding node to Cassandra cluster causes CPU overload on existing nodes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

So, here is our setup so far:

- Cassandra 2.0.10, JDK 1.7.0_65-b17
- 6 nodes (EC2 c3.8xlarge/ 32 cores/60GB RAM, EBS disks for data,
  ephemeral SSD for commit logs etc)
- pretty heavy write load - 100Ks/second
- RF=2, one dc, 2 racks
- everything works just fine with low CPU consumption - load average tends to be around 4-10

Now, we are trying to add a node. This cases a heavy load on existing nodes - like over 100 load average. The cluster becomes unresponsive, writes and reads mostly fail.

The weird observations are that:
 - without adding new node CPU is low
 - if we turn off writes while adding a new node load average on existing nodes drops back to 4-10 and the new node just fine

I've checked VisualVM sampling and basically all the CPU on existing nodes is consumed by org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select().

What we tried so far:

- throttling streaming - no impact
- disabling internode compression - no impact
- disabling autocompaction on existing nodes - no impact
- even running with -Dorg.jboss.netty.epollBugWorkaround=true - no impact

And as of now we are somewhat desperate as this behavior is a blocker for us - we can't afford losing writes and we will need to expand C* dynamically.

Anyone has encountered something similar? Any ideas/hints? Thanks

**EDIT**: OS is Ubuntu 12.04

**EDIT**: I still have no idea what causes the behavior above and I'm still curious. OTOH, I've managed to add a couple of nodes w/o any disruption, cpu usage increase, etc by using the following sequence of actions:

- set auto_bootstrap: false
- start node, join
- run nodetool rebuild on this new node
- bingo

This scheme will do as a workaround for our case. But it looks somewhat clumsy

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Cassandra [virtual node](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/virtual-nodes-in-cassandra-1-2)?
I guess with RF=2, when you try to add a new node, 2 existing nodes would be very busy to transfer their data to the new node while responding to your heavy write load at the same time, which would possibly lead to a hot spot problem.

Comment: Sorry, missed this detail - we are using virtual nodes hash ring with 256 tokens. As for heavy load - the thing is that each of activities (join, writes) separately never cause more than,say, load average of 8, which is like 25% of CPU. Together they spin it up to, 300% cpu (LA like 120)

Comment: oh OK. Actually we never add nodes at such a heavy run time, instead we do it in the night or weekends. Your write load is always such heavy? Our cluster spec is much lower than yours and we did have some trouble to add new nodes, but the result is finally good.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately the load is permanent. Actually, this is only a PoC now and in production we expect x4 load:-(

Comment: oh OK, I'll keep an eye on your issue and see if it would be solved. Do give me an update about this, thanks

Comment: Sure, I will. Thanks for prompt reaction and support